# How to open IE int the background no window should be displayed?

Tags: internet-explorer

I am deveoloping an application. Which requires a browser(IE) to run. But evrytime the window is opening. Im running IE by executing a batch file. My requirement is IE window should not be visible.
Can anybody suggest me Please Please....!

Answer (score 0):

Try this VB Script.

```
Visible = 0 'it won't show

Set objExplorer = WScript.CreateObject _
("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
objExplorer.Navigate "http://www.google.com"

'Determines if the window is visible or not
objExplorer.Visible = 0

'Suspend the script for 1 minute
WScript.Sleep 60000

'Close the IE (instantiated) window
objExplorer.quit

Sub IE_onQuit()
Wscript.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks,
Can u write this script in c#

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a line of powershell

```
powershell -Command "& {Start-Process -WindowStyle Minimized iexplore.exe}"
```