# How to run an internet browser in the background without window?

Tags: batch-file

How can I run an internet browser with an url, any url I want, and it opens but it opens in background without showing a window?

It should be like a background media player. And if you know how to do that please tell me and tell me how I can mute the browser once starting. I am trying to do this with a batch file.

Comment: Could you explain what it is actually supposed to do if the window is both invisible and muted?

You can't interact with the actual website using only a .bat script. It'll have to be a hybrid (VBS for example) or some other external program. It's possible with a simple VBS to download something and then execute/open it silently.

Comment: It doesn't have to be muted I just wanna how can I run do the following: open any link - opens the browser (but hidden/no window) it could be used for like a secret player or something like that.

Comment: ok well how do i do it in VBS then?

Comment: I'd only use a VBS to create a document with the html of the page, which is unnecessary if you want to open the window only. In retrospect, I'd recommend powershell.

Comment: Ok so i found this VB Script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066633/how-to-open-ie-int-the-background-no-window-should-be-displayed

Comment: but im wondering how can i mute something with VB script?

Comment: You can actually make it much simpler like this: `createobject("Wscript.Shell").run """"&"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642194"&"""",0,false`. I don't believe you can mute a specific application without third-party software. Have a look at [NirCMD](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

Comment: Hmm thanks for your help <3 could it be possible to do in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a hidden window with powershell. You can use powershell commands within cmd or in a .bat file as well. Here's an example:

```
powershell saps 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642194' -wi hidden
```

That opens a hidden window of your default browser with the specified link.

Comment: and if i wanted it muted? what should i add to it?